# How to upgrade Scipy in Kaggle notebooks

Tags: python, scipy, pip, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I want to upgrade Scipy to get another library to work.

[image]

You can see I have tried to upgrade Scipy using

```
!pip install --upgrade scipy
```

and it looks like I did a successful upgrade, but when I am checking my scpiy version afterwards it's still 1.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaggle kernels are interactive sessions running in a Docker container with pre-installed packages.

Try changing them using the settings option in the kernel editor then clicking the packages option you can customize packages.

This can be done by accessing the “Settings” tab in the Notebook editor. Once you upgrade the package under Settings-->Docker-->you will options "Original" and "Latest available". Select the latest available, then you can use your updated packages.

Next to “Docker image”, there is a dropdown menu containing all Docker images you’ve created when installing new packages. Pin a specific Docker image for use in a Notebook if there are multiple custom images available. You can select one of the images to be used persistently within that Notebook.

Hope it will help